# Is git pull really git fetch + git merge?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I was practicing git in the following sandbox: https://learngitbranching.js.org/?NODEMO

I ran two sets of commands in two separate sessions. The first set of commands in order is as follows:

```sh
git clone
git checkout -b feature
git push
git fakeTeamwork main 1
git fakeTeamwork feature 1
git pull
```

The second set of commands in order are similar but I use `git fetch` + `git merge` at the end instead:

```sh
git clone
git checkout -b feature
git push
git fakeTeamwork main 1
git fakeTeamwork feature 1
git fetch
git merge o/feature
```

If `git pull` = `git fetch` + `git merge`, why are the two outcomes different? It seems that `git pull` does not update all the remote tracking branches. Is this just a flaw of the sandbox or is this actually what happens in git?

Note: The commands `git clone` and `git fakeTeamwork` are just commands built for the sandbox

Thank you!

Comment: in what way are the outcomes different?

Comment: It seems that git pull does not update all the remote-tracking branches.

Comment: how did you verify that? I could test the same thing locally if you'd like

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It seems that git pull does not update all the remote tracking branches.

This *can* happen, yes.  It *does* happen when:

- `git pull` runs `git fetch origin master`, for instance, and
- `git fetch origin master` therefore only updates `origin/master`.

Futhermore, in Git versions predating 1.8.4, some `git fetch` operations do not update any remote-tracking names at all.  Here the `git fetch origin master` has no effect on `origin/master`.

Besides these, we have several other special cases:

- If `git pull` is configured or told to run `git rebase`, the second command it uses is `git rebase`, not `git merge`.  The obvious substitute is thus `git fetch` followed by `git rebase`.  Some specifics here are even-more Git version dependent, though: in particular, `git pull` implemented `--fork-point` mode for rebase before `git rebase --fork-point` existed (the actual `--fork-point` option first occurring in Git 1.9, but `git pull` doing special work since some 1.6 version—I looked up the precise version once, but these days the oldest Git in use seems to be for CentOS, which includes some Git 1.7 versions in some distributions).
- There is one *very* special case: if you create an empty repository, add a remote, and run `git pull`, there is no existing branch yet.  (You can trigger this case again later using orphan branches.)  In this case instead of either merge or rebase, `git pull` runs a specialized `git checkout`.

The *upstream* setting of a branch matters here, depending on what arguments you pass to `git pull` or to the fetch and second commands.  In general these mostly end up working the same way, except for the caveat you noted about some remote-tracking names sometimes not getting updated.

Comment: Why would a plain `git pull` without additional parameters actually run `git fetch origin master` and not just `git fetch`? I understand the documentation so that it uses the given parameters

Comment: In the old script version of `git pull`, the call to `git fetch` was (after removing pull-specific options) `git fetch "$@"`. So options were passed through exactly as specified. In the rewritten C version, this might be different. (The C rewrite is new in Git 2.6.0.)

Comment: I don't use the C version myself, so I'm not sure if it does this—plus, it post-dates Git 2.0 which means it probably matters less since 1.8.4 fixed the opportunistic update thing—but one of the goals of passing extra parameters on the command line was to limit `git fetch` to make the fetch run faster. So `git pull origin master` ran `git fetch origin master`, which didn't (and still doesn't) bother fetching any *other* branches.

Comment: If we're on branch X with upstream R/X, it thus makes some sense to run `git fetch R X` to make it go faster. Does it do that? I'd have to experiment, and then I would get an answer for one specific version of Git: maybe the answer differs in other versions. If you run `git fetch` yourself, *you're* providing the arguments, so you get whatever behavior you specify.

Comment: In general, the documentation doesn't get this fine-grained, so we're left with "whatever someone chose to do, which may change in the next release". :-)

Comment: Also, `git pull` gives different error than `git fetch && git merge` when the remote repository is empty (or the branch does not exist on remote repository).

Answer (score 2):

> Is `git pull` really `git fetch` + `git merge`?

In short, yes.

However, it's worth pointing out that *which* remote tracking branches are updated by `git fetch` (when invoked without any arguments) is determined by the [`remote.<repository>.fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#CRTB) configuration variable.

If you run `git config remote.origin.fetch` in a real Git repo, you should see the following:

```bash
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

This is called a [*refspec*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt-ltrefspecgt). The `*` is telling Git to fetch all branches in the `origin` remote (the right-hand side of the `:`) and put them in your local repo (the left-hand side of the `:`). If you run `git pull` or `git fetch` without any arguments, all new and existing remote tracking branches are going to be updated thanks to this setting.

From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#CRTB):

> When `git fetch` is run without specifying what branches and/or tags
> to fetch on the command line, e.g. `git fetch origin` or `git fetch`,
> `remote.<repository>.fetch` values are used as the refspecs—​they
> specify which refs to fetch and which local refs to update. The
> example above will fetch all branches that exist in the `origin` (i.e.
> any ref that matches the left-hand side of the value, `refs/heads/*`)
> and update the corresponding remote-tracking branches in the
> `refs/remotes/origin/*` hierarchy.

This behavior no longer applies once you start passing the branch name to `git pull` or `git fetch`, as [@torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68935158/26396).

Answer (score 1):

You can use env. variable `GIT_TRACE=1` to see what `git` does roughly. E.g. with my git 2.42:

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git pull
# ... shortened ....
trace: run_command: git fetch --update-head-ok
trace: run_command: git merge FETCH_HEAD
```

Of course, git does other things beside these commands (e.g. making decisions, issuing errors based on a local state). Note: you may see other `run_command:` traces, they are part of `fetch` or `merge`.